A question on how to choose parameters such that a function decays to $-\infty$ when $n$ increases
Question
how to choose $p,\delta$ such that
$$n\log(\frac{100}{\delta})-\frac{n^2\delta^2p}{64(1-p)+6\delta}$$ increases when $n$ grows.
Motivation
I am trying to understand Corollary 5.7 in this paper. The corollary 5.7 is based on lemma 5.6, which proves that certain inequality holds with probability at least $$1-4\exp\Big(n\log\Big(\frac{100}{\delta}\Big)-\frac{n^2\delta^2p}{64(1-p)+6\delta}\Big)$$ where $0<\delta<1$.
And I think corollary 5.7 gives a choice of $p,\delta$ such that the above probability grows towards $1$ when $n$ grows. The choice is $$p=\frac{32\gamma\log n}{n^{1/3}}$$ $$\delta=\frac{1}{n^{1/3}}$$
where $\gamma \geq 1$. In this case the probability is $$1-4\exp\Big(n-\Big(\log(100 n^{1/3})-\frac{\gamma\log n}{2}\Big)\Big)$$
But I have no idea how to obtain the choice of $p,\delta$.
It would be much grateful if someone could give a hint.

which paper is this?

@Physiker sorry, I just update the link in the post
